# Is it possible to wrap fields of a Typescript interface?

Tags: typescript

I have 2 pretty similar interfaces:

```
interface Foo {
  value: boolean;
  time: string;
}

interface ReactiveFoo {
  value: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  time: BehaviorSubject<string>;
}
```

I would prefer to avoid the code duplication and make the `ReactiveFoo` interface to kind of extend `Foo`. I know that there are [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) such as `Partial` or `Readonly`

**Maybe is it a way to do something like this** (doesn't work):

```
type ReactiveFoo = Wrapped<Foo, BehaviourSubject>
```

**P.S.** Also `BehaviourSubject` is a generic type, that required an argument, not sure if it's possible to pass it without an argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to hard code the `BehaviorSubject` type as such

```
type Wrap<Rec> = { [k in keyof Rec]: BehaviorSubject<Rec[k]> };

type Wrapped = Wrap<Foo>;
```

But I didn't find a way to actually pass a generic type (such as `BehaviorSubject`) as a parameter to another generic type (which would be `Wrap` in this particular example)

Comment: This is because TS does not support higher kinded types